# POST to check in mysql databse

Tags: php, mysql, post

**how can i check with php if the username and password are exist in mysql database via a POST method from postman ?**

Comment: Share your full code please

Comment: i want to know the code please

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26222549/php-mysql-check-if-username-and-password-are-in-the-database

Answer (score -1):

Use while loop with mysql_fetch_assoc() and query.

Your HTML can looks like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Your PHP can looks like this:

```
    if(isset($_POST["name"], $_POST["password"])) 
    {   
    $name = $_POST["name"]; 
    $password = $_POST["password"]; 

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT username, password FROM Users WHERE username = '".$name."' AND  password = '".$password."'");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $check_username=$row['username'];
        $check_password=$row['password'];
    }

    if($username == $check_username && $password == $check_password)
    {
        echo "Matches.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No match.";
    }
    }
```